# Filter list of enums by multiple enum constants ("types" of the enum)[Kotlin]

Tags: kotlin, enums

I have a list of enum constants (types) of the same enum object. How can I filter the list by multiple constants?

I have tried this:

```
val list = dataList.filter {
            when(it.type){
                Type.ACTIVE,
                Type.RENEWED,
                Type.OTHER -> {}
            }
        }
```

Comment: Since you want to filter a list, have you considered using `filter`? So you get: `list.filter {it == MyEnumClass.type}`. Where `it` represents your list element and `MyEnumClass.type` represents your preferred type.

Comment: Yup, how I can do that when I need to filter by multiple types? (I've updated my question)

Comment: you either do `list.filter { it == type1 || it == type2 || it == type3 }`, or you do what [Ivo Beckers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1514861/ivo-beckers) suggested with the `when` statement (the `when` statement is better btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should work:

```
val list = dataList.filter {
    when(it.type){
        Type.ACTIVE,
        Type.RENEWED,
        Type.OTHER -> true
        else -> false
    }
}
```